# How is Current Maintenance Margin calculated by Interactive Brokers?

Tags: margin, interactive-brokers

I am curious about how Interactive Brokers calculates Current Maintenance Margin and Current Initial Margin. Why do both have the same value?

I have an all-stock account.

Comment: Is this a margin account with > $25k in it?

Comment: Yes, above 25k.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that I asked about the $25k is that a Pattern Day Trader is allowed 25% margin intraday but must revert to 50% by the EOD for overnight margin.

Margin maintenance is also 25%.  For some reason, Interactive Brokers displays both Current Maintenance Margin and Current Initial Margin at 25%.  AFAIC, they should display the 50% overnight margin amount.